# Custom comparison operator and custom class for std::set in C++

Tags: c++, char, set, compare, stdset

I would like to create a set containing the objects of my class, I have to determine a custom comparison. Unfortunately, everything I tried did not work.

```
class My_Class {
    public:
        char letter;
        set<My_Class, compare> Children;
};
```

Ant then, the compare struct:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const My_Class& a, const My_Class& b) const{
        return a.letter < b.letter;
    }
};
```

How can I make this work please?

Currently, the issue displays that identifiers `a` and `b` are not declared.

Comment: Can you expound upon "did not work"?

Comment: Looks like you may be missing MyClass.h (or whatever) in `compare`'s file. Also, you should probably have `operator()` take `const My_Class&` rather than making a copy.

Comment: @dlf It is not possible, because both `compare` and `My_Class` are in the same file. I tried to use `My_Class&` but I had the same problem.

Comment: Is `compare` above `My_Class`, then?

Comment: `I would like to create a set containing the objects of my class`  Why did you make the `set` a member of My_Class?

Comment: @Paul Thank you, it seems to solve the issue!

Comment: I think that another issue is the usage of an incomplete type (`My_Class`) within itself as you're doing now when you create a `set<My_Class, compare>`.  That's why I asked why you're declaring a set of a `My_Class` within `My_Class`.

Comment: @Paul I read your answer too quickly, I thought you were suggesting me to put `struct compare{}` inside `My_Class{}`, which had the effect to work. To answer you, each object `My_Class` must contain other objects of this type, so I need a set of `My_Class` in `My_Class`, 
I do not know how I could do anything else.

Comment: @user3779937 - That may be so, but I highly suggest you use a different approach such as decoupling that `set` from My_Class. There is no guarantee that the code will compile. Please take a look here: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `compare` structure inside `My_Class`, which uses `My_Class` in its method. It is not a trivial case, but forward declaration will help. So this should work:

```
class My_Class;

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const My_Class &a, const My_Class &b) const;
};

class My_Class {
public:
    char letter;
    set<My_Class, compare> Children;
};

bool compare::operator() (const My_Class &a, const My_Class &b) const
{
    return a.letter < b.letter;
}
```

Another alternative would be to pass comparator to std::set constructor, rather than specify it as a template parameter:

```
class My_Class {
public:
    My_Class();
    char letter;
    set<My_Class> Children;
};

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const My_Class& a, const My_Class& b) const{
        return a.letter < b.letter;
    }
};

My_Class::My_Class() : Children( compare() )
{
}
```

Comment: See my last comment. I think that the code doesn't even have to compile successfully due to using `set<T>` within the definition of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it is not guaranteed to compile.  The problem is not the `compare` struct, so take that out of the picture.  It is this:

```
class My_Class {
public:
    char letter;
    set<My_Class, compare> Children;  // it is the set<My_Class> that is the problem
};
```

You are defining a `std::set` of `My_Class` before the definition of My_Class is known to the compiler.  In other words, you're using an incomplete type within the `std::set` container.  There is no guarantee that the code will compile, and even if it did, the behavior now is undefined.

If you want a container that works with incomplete types, you can use the Boost container types here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container.html

Here is the description about Incomplete Types within the Boost documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types